# Unable to connect to database on host 'http://namenode.tarun.com:7432' from host 'namenode.tarun.com

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager, cloudera-cdh

i have installed cloudera manager server while doing the configuration of database setup of embedded database. The error is given below :

Unable to connect to database on host 'http://namenode.tarun.com:7432' from host 'namenode.tarun.com' using the credential provided

here is my db.mgmt.properties i have changed it becoz it was not recognizing the host name earlier.

login as: root
root@10.182.1.114's password:
Last login: Mon Apr 28 14:29:55 2014 from n1.tarun.com
[root@namenode ~]# vi /etc/cloudera-scm-server/db.mgmt.properties

20140424-144947
these are database credentials for databases created by "cloudera-scm-server-db" for
Cloudera Manager Management Services,
 to be used during the installation wizard if
 the embedded database route is taken.

The source of truth for these settings
 is the Cloudera Manager databases and
 changes made here will not be reflected
 there automatically.

`com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.type=postgresql
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.host=http://namenode.tarun.com:7432
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.name=amon
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.user=amon
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.password=TDBw6Cjo7y
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.type=postgresql
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.host=http://namenode.tarun.com
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.name=rman
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.user=rman

    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.password=computer1
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.type=postgresql
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.host=7432
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.name=nav
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.user=nav
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.password=MNWOjKZdVD
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.type=postgresql
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.host=http://namenode.tarun.com:7432
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.name=amon
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.user=amon
    com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.password=DBG22fU5Jr
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.type=postgresql
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.host=http://namenode.tarun.com
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.name=rman
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.user=rman
    com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.password=computer1
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.type=postgresql
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.host=:7432
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.name=nav
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.user=nav
    com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.password=a5gJFtI758`

Answer (score 0):

```
com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.type=postgresql
**com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.host=:7432**
com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.name=amon
com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.user=amon
com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.password=TDBw6Cjo7y
com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.type=postgresql
**com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.host=7432**
com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.name=rman 
com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.user=rman
com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.password=computer1 
com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.type=postgresql 
**com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.host=:7432** 
com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.name=nav 
com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.user=nav 
com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.password=MNWOjKZdVD
com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.type=postgresql
**com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.host=localhost:7432**
com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.name=amon
com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.user=amon
com.cloudera.cmf.ACTIVITYMONITOR.db.password=DBG22fU5Jr
com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.type=postgresql
**com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.host=localhost:7432**
com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.name=rman
com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.user=rman
com.cloudera.cmf.REPORTSMANAGER.db.password=computer1
com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.type=postgresql
**com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.host=localhost:7432**
com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.name=nav 
com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.user=nav  
com.cloudera.cmf.NAVIGATOR.db.password=a5gJFtI758
```

My db.mgmt.properties is different than yours. I notified the changes with mine with stars. Hope it will help you.